# How do I store the results of a shell command in a makefile?

Tags: shell, makefile

Locally I'm usin GNU Make 3.8 on MacOS (i386-apple-darwin11.3.0)

I'm trying to generate a bunch of test files based on the files in a directory.

Right now I'm able to grab the basename of the files, but I cant figure out how to store them in a variable so I can generate another file with the basename

```
TEST_FILES = lib/*.js

build-test:
    @mkdir -p tests
    -@for file in $(TEST_FILES); do \
        echo $$file; \
        MYNAMES = $(basename $$file .js) \
        echo $MYNAMES; \
    done
```

I want to then create a bunch of files called $MYNAME.log using output from a STDOUT stream.

I'm stuck on getting the names into the variable, the solutions [I've found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2019989/how-to-assign-the-output-of-a-command-to-a-makefile-variable) [so far](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10024279/how-to-use-shell-commands-in-makefile) are throwing errors for me when I try to implement them

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to do, how you're trying to do it or whether you're using a good approach. Suppose you have `lib/foo.js` and `lib/bar.js`, what then?

Comment: @beta should make a file called test/foo.log test/bar.log

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This line here

```
echo $MYNAMES; \
```

will substitute in the value of the make variable `M`, as if you wrote $(M)YNAMES. You want

```
echo $$MYNAMES; \
```

instead.

This line

```
   MYNAMES = $(basename $$file .js) \
```

cannot work - you are using a make command `basename` which is executed only once before the subshell is invoked to execute the rule, whereas `file` is a shell variable which changes each iteration of the loop. You probably meant `$$(basename $$file)` instead, which will be passed to the shell as "$(basename $file)". The shell will insert the results of running the `basename` command.

Make sure that you do want to store them in a shell variable, and not as a make variable. It's essential to understand the difference.

Comment: In short: You need to escape every $ in a Makefile that is meant to be used in the shell script.

Comment: @Gavin_Smith I tried that method too -- MYNAMES = $$(basename $$file); \ echo $MYNAMES; \ -- then I get "/bin/bash: MYNAMES: command not found"

Comment: There should be no space between the variable name and the `=` sign (this is different syntax from that for assigning make variables).

Comment: @GavinSmith ok now I'm getting no errors but how do I use the variable now? like how do I echo the contents of it, currently it shows empty

Comment: Reread my answer and previous comments - if you've quoted what you're doing accurately then the answer has already been given.

Comment: Another mistake you might be making is executing multiple commands. Each line (not ending with \\) in a make recipe is run using a separate shell, and environment variables are not shared therebetween. To avoid this, use \ at the end of lines to pass it all to one shell sub-process.