# Executing Shell command in Makefile rule

Tags: bash, unix, makefile

I am trying to **run a shell command from Makefile rule section**. I'm using `basename` command to get file name couldn't provide correct file name through `$$file` . anyone please, help.

```
for file in `ls *.fof`; \
   do \
   $(eval VIP = `basename $$file .fof`) \
   echo "filename with ext. is $$file"; \
   echo "filename is $(VIP)";\
done
```

Comment: More generally perhaps see also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10024279/how-to-use-shell-commands-in-makefile

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While you can get there that way, **basename**(1) is hardly ever needed.

- In the shell, the pattern `${file##*/}` removes the directory, and  `${file%.*}` removes the extension.  As built-ins, they're faster than invoking an executable.
- In GNU make, you have $(notdir $(basename $(file))).  BSD make has similar.

I try to avoid loops in make.  To accomplish what you're doing, I might do something like

```
.SUFFIXES = .fof .T
NAMES=$(wildcard *.fof)

all: $(subst .fof,.T,$(NAMES))

.fof.T: 
        echo "filename with ext. is $^"
        echo "filename is $(notdir $(basename($@)))"
```

Answer (score 0):

I could make it work with small changes:

```
all:
    for file in `ls *.txt`; \
       do \
       VIP=`basename $$file .txt` ;\
       echo "filename with ext. is $$file"; \
       echo "filename is $$VIP";\
    done
```

1. changes in the `VIP=` line
2. the last echo uses `$$VIP`