# Store the result of a command in Makefile in a variable

Tags: bash, makefile

In a Makefile, how can I store the output of a command as a variable?

I am trying:

```
vm_instance_name = foo
registry = us.gcr.io/acmeinc
image_name = bar
image_tag = $(docker images ${registry}/${image_name} | awk '{print $2}' | awk 'NR==2')

deploy:
    gcloud beta compute instances update-container $(vm_instance_name) --container-image=$(registry)/$(image_name):$(image_tag)
```

But that's not working. `$image_tag` is empty.

Comment: Is your question about first assignment (missing `shell` call or backtick syntax) or second one that's already inside recepie?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10024279/how-to-use-shell-commands-in-makefile