# How to use lsof inside of Makefile

Tags: bash, makefile, lsof

Suppose I have something like

```sh
.PHONY: kill-server
kill-server:
   kill -9 $(lsof -t -i :9000)
```

Why it doesn't work and how do I fix this?

Comment: You did not specify, which _make_  you are using, but in all those which I know, `$(FOO)` expands the varialbe `FOO` inside make. See for instance [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Reference.html#Reference).

Comment: @user1934428 but for calling functions I do use `$()` as well, don't I? https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Syntax-of-Functions.html#Syntax-of-Functions

Comment: For make functions, but _lsof_ is not a make function. Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10024279/how-to-use-shell-commands-in-makefile) help?

Comment: `$(lsof -t -i :9000)` will be expanded by `make` when it reads the makefile.  To defer execution until the point at which the `kill-server` is run use `$$(lsof -t -i :9000)` instead.

Comment: @user1934428 anyway it just doesn't see something like `PID:="$(lsof -t -i:9000)"; echo $(PID)` as been suggested there

Comment: @G.M.: I'm not very proficient in _make_ (that's why I wrote a comment instead of an answer), but would perhaps something like `$(shell kill -9 $(lsof ...))`  do the job?

Comment: @AdilAkhmetov : For a practical solution, wouldn't it make sense to put the whole shell code into a shell script, and invoke the script from your Makefile? Doing this avoids mixing make and shell syntax and is likely easier to debug too.

Comment: @G.M. thanks, now it seems to work. But how do I use it in  if statements like `ifneq ($$(lsof -t -i :9000),)`?

Comment: @user1934428 yeah, you're right, but this is only two jobs (run and kill) which I don't want to separate into several files

Comment: Why not? They are different in a fundamental way: A Makefile (which is goal directed), and shell script (simply procedural). They are based on different syntax rules. Is there a logical reason,why they must reside in the same physical file?

Comment: FYI it is not the case that `$(lsof ...)` will be expanded by make "when it reads the makefile".  This is part of a recipe, and a recipe will be expanded by make when make wants to run it, just before the shell is invoked to build the target.  If the target is never built, the recipe will never be expanded.

Comment: @MadScientist Yes, sorry.  My comment was badly worded -- should've been more careful.

Answer (score 1):

You could pipe `lsof` to `xargs` in your makefile:

```
# Makefile - Version 1

# Send kill to server
kill-server:
    lsof -t -i :9000| xargs kill -9
```

Answer (score 0):

Good grief.  So much confusion.

It's very simple: `$` is special to make.  It introduces a *make* variable.  If you write a recipe (which is a *shell script*) and you want the *shell* to see the `$` you have to escape it so that make won't expand it as a make variable.  That's completely trivial to do, you just write `$$` anywhere you want to pass `$` to the shell:

```
.PHONY: kill-server
kill-server:
        kill -9 $$(lsof -t -i :9000)
```

That's it.  Done.