# how can I access makefile variable in xv6?

Tags: makefile, xv6

Now I am trying to access makefile variable in my user program in xv6.
In other linux system, it can be easily achieved by doing that

1. in makefile, define `gcc -D MYVARIABLE=1 ...`
2. in my linux user program, by defining `#include <stdio.h>`, I can access `MYVARIABLE`.

but in xv6, there is no <stdio.h>. so I can't access `MYVARIABLE`.

How can I do for access `MYVARIABLE`??

Comment: It is absolutely no true that you need to `#include <stdio.h>` to access `MYVARIABLE`.  By adding `-DMYVARIABLE=1` to the command line you've created a _preprocessor_ variable named `MYVARIABLE` and it will be available anywhere in that source file, regardless of what headers you include or don't include.

Comment: @MadScientist oh.. I confused the usage.. thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Guessing you use this repo: https://github.com/mit-pdos/xv6-public, you can define `MYVARIABLE` in `CFLAGS` declaration, near line 83.

```
CFLAGS = -fno-pic -static -fno-builtin -fno-strict-aliasing -O2 -Wall -MD -ggdb -m32 -Werror -fno-omit-frame-pointer
CFLAGS += $(shell $(CC) -fno-stack-protector -E -x c /dev/null >/dev/null 2>&1 && echo -fno-stack-protector)
# Your macro here
CFLAGS += -DMYVARIABLE=1
```

In that makefile, there is no `%.o: %.c` rule: [implicit rules](https://web.mit.edu/gnu/doc/html/make_10.html) are used:

> `n.o` is made automatically from `n.c` with a command of the form `$(CC) -c $(CPPFLAGS) $(CFLAGS)`

Comment: really thank you for repply!

do you happen to know how can I change the MYVARIABLE dynamically by using `make MYVARIABLE=something`??

I try this, but in my source file, it doesn't change.. :(

Comment: @moon Warning, The `MYVARIABLE` in you source code is not a variable, but a macro, it will be replaced by the value you give. Anyway, you can have dynamic value, evaluated when `make` is called, see [that question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10024279/1212012)