# What is the difference between using $(shell) vs directly executing the command in Makefile?

Tags: makefile

Here's my `Makefile`

```
AA = $(shell date)
a:
    @echo $(AA)
    $(shell sleep 1)
    @echo $(AA)
    $(shell sleep 1)
    @echo $(AA)

b:
    @echo $(AA)
    @sleep 1
    @echo $(AA)
    @sleep 1
    @echo $(AA)
```

Here's my output.

```
>make a
Wed Apr 26 20:24:14 PDT 2023
Wed Apr 26 20:24:15 PDT 2023
Wed Apr 26 20:24:16 PDT 2023

>make b
Wed Apr 26 20:24:18 PDT 2023
Wed Apr 26 20:24:18 PDT 2023
Wed Apr 26 20:24:18 PDT 2023
```

What is the difference between running `sleep 1` vs `$(shell sleep 1)` ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use shell commands in Makefile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10024279/how-to-use-shell-commands-in-makefile)

Comment: Isn't it obvious? The `$(shell sleep 1)` gets evaluated as `make` parses the `Makefile`. This is a common beginner FAQ (or, more like, commonly misunderstood, but rarely actually asked).

Comment: `AA` is an extraordinarily bad way to run `date` when you want its output. Besides the [useless use of `echo`](https://www.iki.fi/era/unix/award.html#echo) you are also complicating things needlessly with the `make` variable and the `$(shell ...)` indirection. This also complicates the result - I thought you had mixed up the output from `a` and the output from `b` because of this unobvious complication. In `b` the shell function runs when the recipe is evaluated, and _then_ you sleep between the statements which print the output.

Comment: To make it short: never use `$(shell ...)` in recipes. Recipes are already shell scripts. If you want to run `date` or `sleep` in a recipe, just run them like you do with `echo`. And if you use a make variable to easily reuse a shell command in recipes just assign it the shell command (`AA = date`). By the way, can you explain why you run the `echo` shell command as is in the recipe but think that other commands like `date` or `sleep` could need the use of `$(shell ...)`?.

Comment: my question is more toward, why when I used `sleep 1` the `$(AA)` is the same, whereas when i used `$(shell sleep 1)`, the `$(AA)` is 1s apart.

Comment: In `a`, both `date` and `sleep` are executed by the parser, therefore the date changes. In `b`, only `date` is executed by the parser, then `echo` and `sleep` are executed by the recipe. In that case, `echo` only prints precomputed result from the parser, so the date doesn't change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What is the difference between running `sleep 1` vs `$(shell sleep 1)` ?

Bare `sleep 1` in a recipe is executed when the recipe runs.  `$(shell sleep 1)` in a recipe is executed when `make` expands variable and function references in the recipe, *before* (any of) it runs.

This makes a difference in your example because

- `AA` is a recursively expanded variable (the only kind supported by traditional `make`), and
- `make` fully expands the recipe before executing any of it, and
- `make` expands variable and function references in the recipe in the order they appear.

Therefore, when you `make b`, variable `$(AA)` is (recursively) expanded three times, one right after the other, which is very likely to produce the same result each time.  Each of those results is interpolated into the recipe.  ***Then*** the recipe is run, and the `sleep`s happen in between printing the previously-computed, likely identical timestamps.

On the other hand, when you `make a`, the `$(shell sleep 1)` expansions occur while `make` is expanding the recipe, between the expansions of `$(AA)` (which in turn runs `date` and captures the result).  In this case, the three runs of `date` should be expected ordinarily to yield results that differ by the sleep time.

As @RenaudPacalet remarked in comments, you pretty much never want to use `$(shell)` inside a recipe.  It is more than likely to confuse you, and you don't need it there, because recipes are executed by the shell already.  Just write shell code.

Personally, I recommend avoiding `$(shell)` altogether, and most other GNU `make` "functions" as well, for the sake of portability.  Not all `make`s are GNU `make`.